# Convert string into a column name and work with function in r

Tags: r

I have data that with multiple y (y1 and y2). I want to run a loop to construct *newdata*, conditioning on y is not missing. I tried to run the code as below, but it didn't work:

```
y1 <- c(1,NA,0,1,1)
y2 <- c(NA,NA,0,1,0)
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x2 <- c(2,3,4,5,6)
x3 <- c(3,4,5,6,7)

mydata <- data.frame(y1,y2,x1,x2,x3)

y <- c("y1","y2")

for (i in 1:length(y)){
  text <- paste0("mydata$",y[i])
  newdata<-mydata[is.na(eval(as.name(text)))==F,]
}
```

Error in eval(as.name(text)) : object 'mydata$y1' not found

Comment: Right, because `mydata$y1` is not a name. It’s a compound expression, consisting of the `$` operator and two names. You don’t need to do any of these contortions (and using `eval()` for such things is generally not a good idea!). To use a column name stored in a string you can use `[[`: `mydata[[y[i]]]`.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a vector of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-character-value). See also [Difference between `[` and `[[`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)
.

Comment: Missing from your example is the definition of `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this is what you're after:

```
for (i in 1:length(y)){
  newdata<-mydata[is.na(eval(mydata[[i]]))==F,]
}
```

`newdata` should then look like this:

|  | y1 | y2 | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 6 | 7 |